# Using background image in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, getelementbyid

I'm using this (javascript) code statement to see if an item has already been selected:

```
if (document.getElementById("someID").style.backgroundImage != 'url("images/bg_selected.png")' {
  dothis
}
```

It works in `firefox` and `IE` but not `chrome`.

How can i get worked with chrome also?

Comment: This is not the correct way of coding to achieve your goal. You should use a variable to toggle when your item is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `data` attribute instead of making logic on the background image. For instance when you select an element you can set `data-selected='true'` and then do

`if (document.getElementById("someID").getAttribute("data-selected") === "true"){do something}`

Answer (score 0):

getComputedStyle get used in the condition

Comment: document.getElementById("someID").getComputedStyle('backGround',null)==image.jpg

Comment: or put backgroundImage I but not i

Comment: sorry getComputedStyle(object,null).image==image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

using jquery we can solve

```
$("#activeObject").css("background-image")
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript

window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("someId"), false).backgroundImage